# Admob and facebook interstitial in the same activity

Tags: java, android, admob, facebook-audience-network

I'm trying to put admob and facebook interstitial in the same activity. But I get 2 erros:
1:
The cronstuctor interstitialAd (HomeActivity, String) is undefined

2:
The method buildLoadAdConfig() is undefined for the type InterstitialAd (build ad config is my code to load facebook ad)

And when I remove the admob Interstitial the app works correctly without errors.

How can I solve the problem please

Answer (score 0):

try to use variable Declaration like this:

```
public static com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd googleFullscreen;
public static com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd facebookFullscren;
```